# BGE: Path follower wait in a specific point

Tags: game-engine, logic-bricks

How can I modify the following .blend file in order for the cube to wait 10 seconds in "point.004". I don't want to use the sleep function.
[Here is the file](http://www.pasteall.org/blend/32390)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply switch to a different state, in which you do nothing but wait to switch back to the original state.

That could look like this:

```
def wait(self, seconds):
    self["clock"] = 0
    sen_prop = self.sensors["Property"]
    sen_prop.min = str(seconds)
    sen_prop.max = str(seconds + 1)
    self.state = 2
```

And then to use it:

```
wait(cont.owner, 10)
```

The function assumes the presence of a Timer property called "clock", and a property sensor (called "Property") in state 2, connected to a state actuator that switches back to the original state.

Here's a modified version of your demo, that shows this in action: [track_to_point.blend](https://www.dropbox.com/s/75lm38dtlz9o399/wait_at_point.blend?dl=1)